# Invalid JSON RPC response: undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, rpc, ethereum, solidity

I'm trying to create an Ethereum account through Node.js. This is my code:

```
export async function createNewAccount() {
    var web3Instance =  new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
    return web3Instance.eth.accounts.create();
}
```

But I'm getting the following error (from 'create' function):

> Invalid JSON RPC response: undefined

I have installed web3.js in my project.

What other step have I missed?

BTW opening the browser on address http://localhost:8545 returns 404. Is there anything I need to install in order to make it work? Is that the testrpc?

Notice that I want to work against the real blockchain, not a test one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web3.js is only a javascript interface that can deal with a real node, in order to conduct RPC requests you must have an ethereum node running this can be either 
TestRPC , Parity , Geth. additionally, since you are pointing to localhost you will need to run it on your own

The easiest for you to test with will be [testRPC](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc) install and run it will. By default give you 10 accounts. in order to create a new account with testRPC you will need to run it with `--unlock` option